# Second Reflow with BGA

Tags: pcb, soldering, pcb-fabrication, reflow

For a DIY project BGA reflow soldering is really expensive to get it done by commercial means. I approached a university which allowed me to avail the help of their staff but they said they would only do the BGA part.

I thought of getting the other parts done through commercial means since they don't cost much and then get the BGA done. Would this work?

I checked the datasheets and some components have second reflow capabilities whereas its not specified for others. Can I use something like epoxy glue to hold the others in place while the BGA is being reflowed?

Its a pretty tight knit board with about 300 components packed into a 7cmx4cm board, so I'm pretty concerned about them shifting during the second reflow.

Comment: My first thought is that if you're getting the rest done by a commercial service, you should have them price out doing it with a BGA also.

Comment: Try http://www.7pcb.com/PCB-Assembly-Quote.php for a quote.  I specced out 1 board with a 300 line BOM and 1000 smt pads, with and without 1 BGA package, and there was barely a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be better to use a [hot air rework](http://It%20would%20probably%20be%20better%20to%20use%20a%20hot%20air%20rework%20station%20to%20replace%20the%20BGA) station to replace the BGA. You still have to be careful with components with this method, but it can be done. I would find a service to do this for you.

If not, then even if the other components move around (which they shouldn't move too much because the solder has surface tension that keeps the part in place), you should be able to fix any problems with a hot air rework gun (and flux) or two soldering irons for passives.

No matter what you do its going to be expensive, BGA's are hard to deal with and the process have to be done right because you can't see the connections unless you have an x-ray machine.

Comment: luckily the university has agreed to do this for free and they have an x-ray machine to inspect the joints . I was just concerned about the other parts moving around but this rests my concern .Thank you